# Set's symmetric difference in mutable value creates duplicate

Tags: swift

I want the user to rank an array of options into their liking.
I have 1 array holding original values for Options, 1 array holding updated values from the original. 
How can I get the remaining options?
I'm on Swift 4.2

My idea is to convert both into Sets and use symmetric difference.

**options** array provides the original choice
**ranked** array has value property of user's rank (1,2,3, or 4)
**remainingOptions** should contains fruits that are not ranked yet

However, I get duplicates.

Feel free to suggest other ways.

```swift
struct Option: Hashable {
    var title: String
    var key: String
    var value: Int
}
var apple = Option(title: "Apple", key: "apple", value: 0)
var grape = Option(title: "Grape", key: "grape", value: 0)
var banana = Option(title: "Banana", key: "banana", value: 0)
var papaya = Option(title: "Papaya", key: "papaya", value: 0)

var options = [apple, grape, banana, papaya]

apple.value = 1
grape.value = 2
var ranked = [apple, grape]

let originalSet: Set<Option> = Set(options)
var rankedSet: Set<Option> = Set(ranked)

let remainingOptions = originalSet.symmetricDifference(rankedSet)
```

Result:

```
{title "Grape", key "grape", value 1}
{title "Apple", key "apple", value 0}
{title "Grape", key "grape", value 2}
{title "Banana", key "banana", value 0}
{title "Apple", key "apple", value 1}
{title "Papaya", key "papaya", value 0}
```

Wanted result:

```
{title "Banana", key "banana", value 0}
{title "Papaya", key "papaya", value 0}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are expecting two `Option`s to be equal if they have the same `title` and `key`, but by default Swift is also checking the `value`.  Therefore, two `Option`s with different `value`s are considered different.

Symmetric difference returns a new set with the elements that are either in this set or in the given sequence, but not in both.  Because you have changed the values, you end up with a union of your two sets because they have nothing in common.

You can fix this by explicitly implementing the `hash(into:)` function and `==` functions to ignore the `value` when checking for equality:

```
struct Option: Hashable, CustomStringConvertible {
    var title: String
    var key: String
    var value: Int
    var description: String { return "{title: \"\(title)\", key: \"\(key)\", value: \(value)}" }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(title)
        hasher.combine(key)
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Option, rhs: Option) -> Bool {
        return lhs.title == rhs.title && lhs.key == rhs.key
    }
}

var apple = Option(title: "Apple", key: "apple", value: 0)
var grape = Option(title: "Grape", key: "grape", value: 0)
var banana = Option(title: "Banana", key: "banana", value: 0)
var papaya = Option(title: "Papaya", key: "papaya", value: 0)

var options = [apple, grape, banana, papaya]

apple.value = 1
grape.value = 2
var ranked = [apple, grape]

let originalSet: Set<Option> = Set(options)
var rankedSet: Set<Option> = Set(ranked)

let remainingOptions = originalSet.symmetricDifference(rankedSet)
print(remainingOptions)
```

> ```
> [{title: "Papaya", key: "papaya", value: 0}, {title: "Banana", key: "banana", value: 0}]
> ```

---

**Note:** `symmetricDifference` takes a sequence, so it isn't necessary to convert `ranked` into a `Set`, you can just use the array:

```
let remainingOptions = originalSet.symmetricDifference(ranked)
```

---

**Another Option:  Use Filter**

Instead of using `Set`s and `symmetricDifference`, you can use `map` to get an array of `keys` from the `ranked` array, and then use `filter` on the `options` array to get the `remaining` options that don't match those `keys`:

```
let rankedKeys = ranked.map { $0.key }
let remaining = options.filter { !rankedKeys.contains($0.key) }
```

This doesn't require you to change the `Option` struct from your original definition.

Comment: WOW, thanks a lot! Indeed I tried adding `hash(into:)` but I didn't include `==`!